# Jquery $.post unexpected token <

Tags: jquery, token

I'm about to give up,

Whats wrong with this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('php/taglist.php',{},function(response) {
    var arr = $.parseJSON(response);
    console.log(arr);
    });
    });
</script>
```

That's what I get in my console log:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.min.js:3
b.extend.parseJSON jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous function)
c jquery.min.js:3
p.fireWith jquery.min.js:3
k jquery.min.js:5
r jquery.min.js:5
```

Comment: check console.log(response)  +1 for showing us error msg

Comment: Yeah, I'd imagine you're getting an html error code response rather than JSON, and it's failing to parse.  You might also try installing Fiddler, so you can see the JSON traffic as it goes between your browser and server.

Comment: Yup, you guys got it. the PHP files produce an html Error. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont need '{}' in line

```
  it should be like      $.post('php/taglist.php',function(data) {
```

in your code ..